# What is the Trinitarian explanation or interpretation of Proverbs 8:22

Tags: trinity, persons-of-the-trinity, wisdom

Prov 8:22 (NKJV) says about Wisdom:

> The Lord possessed me at the **beginning** of His way, Before His works of old.

And John 1:1 reads:

> In the **beginning** was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

**Emphasis mine**

-

Wisdom speaks of itself as having existed with God